# Integration of Yet Another Forum with the existing and running blog engine

Tags: integration, yetanotherforum, yaf

i installed yet another forum code successfully.But when i tried to integrate it with blog engine 2.0 it is giving me error as follows:- Could not load file or assembly 'Autofac.Configuration' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.Can anyone suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have choose Clean then you Rebuild your solution's cause Autofac dll sometime Don't get generated. To solve your problem either copy the Autfac.dll from your downloaded files and put them in the bin folder again. I have experienced this problem several times and this solved it.